# Python sum check in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**df1:**

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'id':['val1','val2','val3','val4','val5','val6'],
         'min':['10','10','75','42','20','50'],
         'max':['93','43','122','80','30','105']})
```

**df2:**

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'id':['val1','val2','val5','val1','val5','val2'],
           'check':['55.4','35.8','93','11.5','23.8','3.22']})
```

The objective is to sum the corresponding check column values in **df2** when id matches with **df1** and check if the resultant sum is within **min-max** range in df1 and update values in **result column of df2**.

**Output df:**

```
id            check        result
val1          55.4         positive
val2          35.8         positive
val5          93           positive
val3          10.1         negative
val1          11.5         positive
val5          23.8         positive
val2          3.22         positive
```

Many thanks!

Comment: what about val3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us do `merge` , the `eval`

```
df=df2.merge(df1,how='left').eval('result=check>min and check < max')
Out[621]: 
     id check min max  result
0  val1  55.4  10  93    True
1  val2  35.8  10  43    True
2  val5    93  20  30   False
3  val1  11.5  10  93    True
4  val5  23.8  20  30    True
5  val2  3.22  10  43    True
```

Answer (score 2):

We can merge and use `between`:

```
(df2.merge(df1, on='id', how='left')
   .assign(result=lambda x: np.where(x.check.between(x['min'],x['max']), 
                                     'positive', 'negative')
          )
   .drop(['min','max'], axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
     id check    result
0  val1  55.4  positive
1  val2  35.8  positive
2  val5    93  negative
3  val1  11.5  positive
4  val5  23.8  positive
5  val2  3.22  positive
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html). Then create a new column with [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df3 = df2.merge(df1, how='left', on = 'id')
s = df3.groupby('id')['check'].transform('sum')
df2['result']=np.where(s.lt(df3['max']) & s.gt(df3['min']), 'positive', 'negative')
print(df2)
```

**Output df2**

```
     id check    result
0  val1  55.4  positive
1  val2  35.8  positive
2  val5    93  negative
3  val1  11.5  positive
4  val5  23.8  negative
5  val2  3.22  positive
```